# Algorithm to find sentences in text

Tags: algorithm, math, search, phrase

Friends, I am looking for a good algorithm to search for given verbose phrases in a large text. For simplicity, I consider the text tokenized and all the words already found in it. Thus, if I have a phrase of three words (in fact there may be more words), I first look for the positions of each of these words in the text, so an array of integers is associated with each of the three words in the phrase. Not necessarily these arrays have the same length.

May be some example will be good here. Assume we need to find a phrase "all white cats" from this text:

> ...this is just a dummy text about **cats**. In this text I want to write the phrase that **all cats** are **white** but the fact is not **all cats** are **white**. But in case there are some **white cats**, anyway, we need to **write** about them. **All** facts about the **cats**...

If we assume "this" word have a number 30, then we can create those numbers for each word from the initial phrase:

```
all: 48, 57, 76
white: 51, 60, 67
cats: 37, 49, 58, 68, 80
```

As you can see, we can combine those words in different phases and each "phrase" will have its own "quality". Quality can be calculated as the sum of distances from each word to the virtual "phrase center".

"**all cats** are **white**" are two good phrases with a quality of 3.33. All other words can be combined with phrases, but they will be low-quality.

My question is to find a good algorithm to make a list of all phrases, each phrase will have a center coordinate and numbers of words. I know it can be done by direct calculation of the distance between each word to each word, but it can take ages if we have enough big text and enough long phrases.

To simplify, I think to limit the lookup distance (let's say 5 words) from each word.

But next, I can't imagine how to calculate this faster.

I feel there is a ready algorithm for this, but can't find one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's prepare an intermediate data structure of sorted positions with corresponding words (see `pos_words` below). For each triplet of subsequent words we check that all required words are present, and for valid triplets we calculate the score/quality value.

See the model implementation in Python:

```py
def calculate_score(data):
    def score(positions):
        center = sum(positions) / len(positions)
        return sum(abs(p - center) for p in positions)

    word_set = set(data)
    word_count = len(word_set)
    pos_words = {p: word for word, positions in data.items() for p in positions}
    positions = sorted(pos_words)
    return [
        (positions[i], score(positions[i:i+word_count]))
        for i in range(len(positions) - word_count + 1)
        if set(pos_words[positions[i+j]] for j in range(word_count)) == word_set
    ]

data = {
    "all": [48, 57, 76],
    "white": [51, 60, 67],
    "cats": [37, 49, 58, 68, 80],
}

print(calculate_score(data))
```

The result contains positions of the first word of the triplet together with calculated scores.

```py
[(48, 3.3333333333333357),
 (49, 9.333333333333336),
 (51, 8.666666666666664),
 (57, 3.3333333333333357),
 (67, 11.333333333333329)]
```